# Asymptotic behavior of infinitely many convolutions

Tags: asymptotics, fourier-transform, convolution, central-limit-theorem

What is the $n$th convolution of a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with itself, $f*f*\cdots*f$ in the $n\rightarrow \infty$ limit? Since the Gaussian is a fixed point of convolutions with appropriate rescaling/normalization, is there a general result analogous to the central limit theorem here?

For example the $n$th convolution of a rectangle pulse $\chi$ with itself is the Fourier transform of $\sin^n x / x^n$, which seems to approach a Gaussian with an appropriate normalization. First, is this true, and if so, is this true more generally for a larger class of functions?

Comment: Take the Fourier transform. With appropriate rescaling / renormalization (the Gaussian isn't a fixed point without appropriate rescaling / renormalization) you approach a Gaussian whenever the Fourier transform has a unique maximum which is nondegenerate in the sense that its second derivative (exists and) is nonzero there. I don't know what happens if the Fourier transform doesn't exist or isn't differentiable at its maximum. The rectangle pulse is (after normalization) the pdf of a random variable so the CLT applies to it.

Comment: If $f$ is assumed to be non-negative, I believe this topic has been handled under the name of 'stable distributions'. The gaussian functions are primary examples of this kind, but there is also a plethora of different examples. For instance, the density of the standard Cauchy distribution $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ satisfies $$f^{\ast n}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{n}{n^2+x^2},$$ and so, $n f^{\ast n}(nx) = f(x)$.